# Orthogonal basis with respect to the inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

[image]

I have been trying to see if only two of the vectors are basis for the span, so that I don't have to do gram schmidt process for all three vectors because it gets very complicated with all the t's.

When t = 1, only u1 is a basis for the span, but for all other values of t, I think u1,u2 and u3 are basis for the span.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: The vectors are linearly independent for all values of $t$ except $t = -3/7,1$

Comment: Could you give us some context?  Is this from a textbook?  Do we have any reason to believe that the problem has a neat solution?